# Magento: Product collection from mutual multiple categories

Tags: magento

Lets say I have a product that can be found in three different categories, eg. ID 104, 115 and 126.

Now I want to get a product collection that consists of products, that should also be found in all of the three categories.
This means that a product that has cat id 104 and 115 should not be in the collection, since 126 is missing.

How do I do that? :-)

**Reply to Ape's answer:**

Tried your approach. The first part of my code is as follows:

```
        $_year = $_product->getBbYear();
        $_yearInterval = $this->getYearInterval();
        $_minYear = $_year - $_yearInterval;
        $_maxYear = $_year + $_yearInterval;

        $_minPopularityScore = $this->getMinPopularityScore();

        $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect( Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes() );

        // EXCLUDE PRODUCT FROM COLLECTION
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter( 'entity_id', array( 'nin' => $_product->getId() ) );

        // BUILD PRIMARY COLLECTION
        if ( !$_fallback ) {
            foreach ($categories as $catid) {
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('finset' => $catid));
            }

            // FILTER COLLECTION BASED ON RELEASE YEAR
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('bb_year', array( 'gt' => $_minYear ));
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('bb_year', array( 'lt' => $_maxYear ));

            // FILTER COLLECTION BASED ON POPULARITY SCORE
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('bb_popularity_score', array('gt' => $_minPopularityScore) );

        // BUILD SECONDARY COLLECTION ON FALLBACK
        }
```

However, once I add the loop and adds multiple filters on category_id, the page does not render. However, I don't get any excecptions and also system log is for no help...

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the product's category ids and add a filter for each category:

```
foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $id) {
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('finset' => $id));
}
```

By calling `addAttributeToFilter()` multiple times, you create an `AND` condition